# Youtube APi Limit

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We're content creators and requires Youtube API access for uploading videos on our channel

1000 Videos Monthly we'll be uploading and all videos are in our server

but now the problem is Youtube API Limit, I've read on Forums that limit is just for uploading 1000 videos maximum with API and after that it gets blocked

Is their any way we can upload 1000 Videos on monthly basis with API v3 ? Do we need to apply for exceeding limit ?

or the 1000 Videos Limit is for monthly basis only ?

each video file size is 50 MB

Thanks

Comment: Youtube API quota limits refer to use of API requests. However you did not mention any of this. Instead this seems more like a storage issue. Can you elaborate?

Comment: API charges 1600 Units per video Upload and we will be uploading 30 videos on daily basis, 48,000 Units we'll be spending on daily basis but I read on google Link that maximum with API you can upload only 1000 videos    

My question is simple - Can we choose Youtube API uploading for our channels permanently ? as I am afraid after uploading 1000 videos , youtube will ban us ? 

as in a year we'll be uploading 1000 Videos Monthly X12 = 12,000 Videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quota charges for uploads are ~1605 units per video. You get 50,000,000 units a day. So you can upload ~31,150 videos a day through the YouTube API assuming you make no other API calls

See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

Answer (score 0):

According to the current documentation for the YouTube API v3, you only get 10,000 units per day. So not 31,500 video uploads a day but only 6.25. HUGE difference. May need to do more digging to see how to extend the quota.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started?hl=en